# guzzle allow redirects false does not work

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Guzzle not stopping data from Redirect:

The following guzzle request not preventing redirects always show status 200 while I have tried with postman it returns 302:

```
$response = $client->request(
    'GET', 
    $Url, 
    ['query' => $body], 
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]
    ], 
    ['allow_redirects' => FALSE]
);
$responseHomeNetworkAPI = $response;
echo $response->getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 4):

As I already [said on GitHub](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1949), probably because you use `request()` method in a wrong way. All your three arrays should be combined into one:

```
$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    $Url,
    [
        'query' => $body,
        'headers' => ['Content-Type'  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        'allow_redirects' => false
    ]
);
```

BTW, `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` makes no sense in a GET request.